# When using SASS how can I import a file from a different directory?

Tags: import, sass

In SASS, is it possible to import a file from another directory?  For example, if I had a structure like this:

```
- root_directory
    - sub_directory_a
        - _common.scss
        - template.scss
    - sub_directory_b
        - more_styles.scss
```

template.scss could import _common.scss using `@import "common"` but is it possible for more_styles.scss to import _common.scss?  I tried a few different things including `@import "../sub_directory_a/common"` and `@import "../sub_directory_a/_common.scss"` but nothing seems to work.

Comment: So people don't get too far and waste time, as @Oliver said below recent changes to SASS have made relative paths possible e.g. `@import '../../css/functions'`

Answer (score 84, accepted):

*UPDATE*: Please consider [Mikka's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6555799/177710) first - it should work without flaw if you're only interested in including **subdirectories**. My answer is specific to including directories **other** than subdirectories, but works for those, too. But: It's not the idiomatic way to do it.

---

Looks like some changes to SASS have made possible what you've initially tried doing:

```
@import "../subdir/common";
```

We even got this to work for some totally unrelated folder located in `c:\projects\sass`:

```
@import "../../../../../../../../../../projects/sass/common";
```

Just add enough `../` to be sure you'll end up at the drive root and you're good to go.

Of course, this solution is far from pretty, but I couldn't get an import from a totally different folder to work, neither using `I c:\projects\sass` nor setting the environment variable `SASS_PATH` (from: [:load_paths reference](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#load_paths-option)) to that same value.

Comment: It is "far from pretty"! But this answer is getting lots of upvotes. Is this really considered a better practice than `-I`? If that pathname changes there will be lots of searching and replacing; and it requires the same local folder structure of anyone sharing the .scss

Comment: I advice ignoring this answer completely. Unfortunately it's one of many SO questions, which are answered incorrectly with up votes. If you want your code to break easily, use it. If you want a robust solution, see my answer below.

Answer (score 39):

As per [official docs](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/cli/dart-sass/#load-path), use the `-I` command line switch (abbreviated version of `--load-path`) or [`:load_paths`](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#options) option from Ruby code to add `sub_directory_a` to Sass's load path.

For example, if you're running Sass from `root_directory`, do something like this:

```
sass -I sub_directory_a --watch sub_directory_b:sub_directory_b
```

Then you can simply use `@import "common"` in `more_styles.scss`.

Note that it can be passed multiple times to provide multiple load paths e.g.

```
sass -I sub_directory_a -I sub_directory_b --watch sub_directory_b:sub_directory_b
```

Comment: Chain `-I ` flags to include more than one directory, e.g. `sass -I sub_directory_a -I sub_directory_c --watch sub_directory_b:sub_directory_b`

Answer (score 31):

Using webpack with sass-loader I can use `~` to refer to the project root path. E.g assuming OPs folder structure and that you're in a file inside sub_directory_b:

```
@import "~sub_directory_a/_common";
```

Documentation: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader#resolving-import-at-rules

2021 Edit: using `~` is now deprecated and the link above says:

> Using ~ is deprecated and can be removed from your code (we recommend
> it), but we still support it for historical reasons. Why can you
> remove it? The loader will first try to resolve @import as a relative
> path. If it cannot be resolved, then the loader will try to resolve
> @import inside node_modules.

Comment: This seems to import from `node_modules/` and not from the root of the project.

Comment: I had to add `"sub_directory_a"` to my `includePaths` and use the `@import "common";` syntax when using the Angular CLI which includes sass-loader.

Comment: Agree with Splaktar. From sass-loader docs: webpack provides an advanced mechanism to resolve files. The sass-loader uses Sass's custom importer feature to pass all queries to the webpack resolving engine. Thus you can import your Sass modules from node_modules. Just prepend them with a ~ to tell webpack that this is not a relative import... It's important to only prepend it with ~, because ~/ resolves to the home directory.

Comment: Note that `~/` doesn't seem to refer to the home directory for me. Or any directory I have tried to test. Is there any way to actually try and figure out where this is referring to??

Comment: In case you want to start from project root directory and not from `node_modules`, do  `~/../<path_to_your_scss>` instead of `~<path_to_your_scss>`.

Comment: Warning: Using `~` is deprecated: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader#resolving-import-at-rules

Answer (score 10):

Importing a `.scss` file that has a nested import with a different relative position won't work. the top proposed answer (using a lot of `../`) is just a dirty hack that will work as long as you added enough `../` to reach the root of your project's deployment OS.

The proper way to do this is by following either of the following two options. *I prefer the second one*.

1. **Add the target SCSS path as a search target for the SCSS compiler:** This can be achieved by adding the stylesheets folder into the SCSS config file, this is a function of the framework you are using,

use `:load_paths` at `config.rd` for compass-based frameworks (Ex. rails)

use the following code at `scss-config.json` for `fourseven/meteor-scss`

```
{
  "includePaths": [
    "{}/node_modules/ionicons/dist/scss/"
  ]
}
```

2. [Recommended] **Use absolute path reference** (vs. relative paths).

Example, with `fourseven/meteor-scss`, you can use `{}` to highlight
top-level of your project as per the following example

```
@import "{}/node_modules/module-name/stylesheet";
```

Answer (score 5):

Gulp will do the job for watching your sass files and also adding paths of other file with includePaths.
example:

```
gulp.task('sass', function() {
  return gulp.src('scss/app.scss')
    .pipe($.sass({
      includePaths: sassPaths
    })
    .pipe(gulp.dest('css'));
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Selected answer does not offer a viable solution.

OP's practice seems irregular. A shared/common file normally lives under `partials`, a standard boilerplate directory. You should then add `partials` directory to your config import paths in order to resolve partials anywhere in your code.

When I encountered this issue for the first time, I figured SASS probably gives you a global variable similar to Node's `__dirname`, which keeps an absolute path to current working directory (`cwd`). Unfortunately, it does not and the reason why is because interpolation on an `@import` directive isn't possible, hence you cannot do a dynamic import path.

According to [SASS docs](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html).

You need to set `:load_paths` in your Sass config. Since OP uses Compass, I'll follow that with accordance to documentation [here](http://compass-style.org/help/documentation/configuration-reference/).

You can go with the CLI solution as purposed, but why? it's much more convenient to add it to `config.rb`. It'd make sense to use CLI for overriding `config.rb` (E.g., different build scenarios).

So, assuming your `config.rb` is under project root, simply add the following line:
`add_import_path 'sub_directory_a'`

And now `@import 'common';` will work just fine anywhere.

While this answers OP, there's more.

## Appendix

You are likely to run into cases where you want to import a CSS file in an embedded manner, that is, not via the vanilla `@import` directive CSS provides out of the box, but an *actual* merge of a CSS file content with your SASS. There's another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7111610/import-regular-css-file-in-scss-file), which is answered inconclusively (the solution does not work cross-environment). The solution then, is to use [this](https://github.com/chriseppstein/sass-css-importer) SASS extension.

Once installed, add the following line to your config: `require 'sass-css-importer'` and then, somewhere in your code: `@import 'CSS:myCssFile';`

**Notice the extension must be omitted for this to work.**

However, we will run into the same issue when trying to import a CSS file from a non-default path and `add_import_path` does not respect CSS files. So to solve that, you need to add, yet another line in your config, which is naturally similar:

`add_import_path Sass::CssImporter::Importer.new('sub_directory_a')`

Now everything will work nicely.

P.S.,
I noticed `sass-css-importer` documentation indicates a `CSS:` prefix is required in addition to omitting the `.css` extension. I found out it works regardless. Someone started an [issue](https://github.com/chriseppstein/sass-css-importer/issues/4), which remained unanswered thus far.

Answer (score 3):

`node-sass` (the official SASS wrapper for `node.js`) provides a command line option `--include-path` to help with such requirements.

**Example:**

In `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "build-css": "node-sass src/ -o src/ --include-path src/",
}
```

Now, if you have a file `src/styles/common.scss` in your project, you can import it with `@import 'styles/common';` anywhere in your project.

Refer https://github.com/sass/node-sass#usage-1 for more details.

Comment: just a word of warning as of 2022 node-sass is deprecated https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass

Answer (score 1):

To define the file to import it's possible to use all folders common definitions. You just have to be aware that it's relative to file you are defining it. More about import option with examples you can check [here](https://kolosek.com/sass-import/).

Answer (score 1):

Look into using the includePaths parameter...

"The SASS compiler uses each path in loadPaths when resolving SASS @imports."

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33588202/384884

Answer (score 1):

If using [Web Compiler](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.WebCompiler) in Visual Studio you can add the path to `includePath` in compilerconfig.json.defaults. Then there is no need for some number of `../` since the compiler will use includePath as a location to look for the import.

For example:

```
"includePath": "node_modules/foundation-sites/scss",
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is a half answer.**

Check out [Compass](http://compass-style.org/), with it you can place your `_common.scss` inside a `partials` folder, and then import it with `@import common`, but it works in every file.

Comment: I think Miikka's response was really what I was after but now I am curious about Compass too.  Is the partials directory somehow specific to a particular project?  Or would files put in the partials directory be available "globally," wherever Compass is used?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. From my solution i came into this. So here is your code:

```
- root_directory
    - sub_directory_a
        - _common.scss
        - template.scss
    - sub_directory_b
        - more_styles.scss
```

As far i know if you want to import one scss to another its has to be a partial. When you are importing from different directory name your `more_styles.scss` to `_more_styles.scss`. Then import it into your `template.scss` like this @import `../sub_directory_b/_more_styles.scss`. It worked for me. But as you mentioned `../sub_directory_a/_common.scss` not working. That's the same directory of the `template.scss`. That is why it wont work.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to user sass-loader. It is available as npm package.
It resolves all path related issues and make it super easy.

Answer (score -7):

I was have same problem and i found solution by adding path to file like:

@import "C:/xampp/htdocs/Scss_addons/Bootstrap/bootstrap";

@import "C:/xampp/htdocs/Scss_addons/Compass/compass";

Comment: While a similar answer has been given earlier, absolute path are bit to specific to server as general answer (you did say “like”, of course).