# How to merge css files (not .scss files) by sass or compass

Tags: css, sass

Although I know CSS file is a valid SCSS
but there is some reason ，so I can't change some files subfix to SCSS

global_min.scss

```
@import url("global/reset.css")
@import url("global/frameset.css");
@import url("global/header.css");
....
....
```

Can  sass  or compass merge  it (´･_･`)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Import regular css file in scss file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7111610/import-regular-css-file-in-scss-file)

Answer (score 4):

You can try the [Sass CSS importer plugin](https://github.com/chriseppstein/sass-css-importer), by Chris Eppstein himself :)

Answer (score 2):

http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#import

> @import takes a filename to import. By default, it looks for a Sass
>   file to import directly, but there are a few circumstances under which
>   it will compile to a CSS @import rule:
>
> - If the file’s extension is .css.
> - If the filename begins with http://.
> - If the filename is a url().
> - If the @import has any media queries.
>
> If none of the above conditions are met and the extension is .scss or
>   .sass, then the named Sass or SCSS file will be imported.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that with SASS without renaming the CSS files.

I suggest that you use some kind of CSS compressor to concatenate and minify your CSS code. Please have a look at [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/), currently the most solid approach to handling this kind of tasks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to merge all css files into a single compiled css file, you need to change their extension to sass or scss and make the changes to be compatible with that format.