# gulp concat after sass

Tags: sass, gulp, concatenation, gulp-concat

I would like to take the sass output and concat it to another css regular file.

example:

```
animate.css
app.scss

return gulp.src('app.scss')
    .pipe(sass({
        errLogToConsole: true
    }))
    .pipe(concat(['animate.css', OUTPUT_OF_THE_SASS_ABOVE]))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.public+'css/'))
    .pipe(rename({ extname: '.min.css' }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('css/'))
    .on('end', done);
```

any ideas how to do it?

******* IDEA

maybe is it possible to generate the css file from sass in to a temp location, then concat it with css files, and them simply remove it.
Any ideas how to do it, in a single task?

Comment: Have you considered just importing the css into the sass directly?

Comment: yes checked it, by it says it is not supported to import css from sass file

Comment: Ah, I thought that Sass had that feature (LESS does). [You can work around it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8802999/497418). Otherwise, from what i can see in the docs, `gulp-concat` doesn't allow you to specify additional files to concat, it just concatenates the files specified from gulp.src`.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`gulp-concat` will only concat the files that were specified by `gulp.src` within the current stream. If you've only specified `app.scss`, you can't concatenate additional files on *that* stream.

That doesn't mean you can't create a **new** stream that contains the `app.scss` compiled output and includes `animate.css` as well.

To do this you'll need [merge-stream](https://github.com/grncdr/merge-stream) (`npm install merge-stream`):

```
var gulp,
    sass,
    merge,
    concat,
    rename;

//load dependencies
gulp = require('gulp');
sass = require('gulp-sass');
merge = require('merge-stream');
concat = require('gulp-concat');
rename = require('gulp-rename');

//define default task
gulp.task('default', function () {
    var sassStream,
        cssStream;

    //compile sass
    sassStream = gulp.src('app.scss')
        .pipe(sass({
            errLogToConsole: true
        }));

    //select additional css files
    cssStream = gulp.src('animate.css');

    //merge the two streams and concatenate their contents into a single file
    return merge(sassStream, cssStream)
        .pipe(concat('app.css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.public + 'css/'));
});
```

Comment: Before I found this answer I tried to use `gulp-merge`, which is apparently not the same as `merge-stream`.  Confusing.  This answer clarified for me.

Answer (score 15):

Why not include animate.css as a partial in your main Sass file?

```
@import "animate";
```

And then rename animate.css to _animate.css

you also get more control over how/where your css compiles.

Comment: I have the animate file from bower folder, and I dont want to rename it, I want make this automated easilly

Comment: What about bringing in animate.css from the CDN instead?
`<link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.2.3/animate.min.css">`

Comment: Ah! Thank you, you just saved my ass.

Comment: This method is deprecated and will be removed. See https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/2362

Comment: All valid CSS is also valid Sass so rename `animate.css` to `_animate.scss`