# Ruby/Jekyll sass: directly import .css file not working

Tags: ruby, sass

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7111610/import-regular-css-file-in-scss-file) answer, I should be able to `@import` a `.css` file directly (as opposed to an import link).

However, I have the following situation:

If the file is named `bootstrap.css`

```
@import "../external_components/bootstrap/css/bootstrap";
```

Does not work, because sass can't find the file.

```
@import "../external_components/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css";
```

Does work, but now I have the import link and an extra `.css` file hanging around.

Now, the answer I linked only mentions `libsass` and `node` but I would really like to be able to do something like that with `ruby sass`. Is there a way? Am I not understanding something basic?

My `sass -v` is `3.4` and apparently up-to-date.

Comment: Same problem for me!