# Scss equivalent of Less: @import (inline) "my.css"

Tags: css, sass, styles, less

So I have file `styles_manager.scss` where I have a lot of sytles references and I want doo something like this inside this file:

```
@import (inline) "node_module/animate.css/animate.min.css"; 
@import "../common/bootstrap/config";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap";
@import "../common/variables";
....
```

I will parse it by scss and get output.css . So I want to have animate.min.css body inside output .css.

In less this sis trivial - "(inline)" statement. How to import css file body into SCSS?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7111610/import-regular-css-file-in-scss-file

Comment: @Lowkase If you give short, clear answer using above example (without theoretical and historical background of this problem) I will choose your answer.

Comment: The link is not theoretical, the answer to your question is in the link.  I am all for gaining more upvotes but it is not necessary when the answer to your question already exists.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The answer is: remove '.css' extension in @input statement (this works for sass version >= 3.2). So example above should look like this:

```
@import "node_module/animate.css/animate.min"; 
@import "../common/bootstrap/config";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap";
@import "../common/variables";
....
```

More theoretical and historical background of that topic you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7111610/import-regular-css-file-in-scss-file) (what was mention by @Lowkase in comments below question)

Comment: ruby-sass version 3.4.23 failed to include the css, with ` remove '.css' extension in @import(instead of @input) statement`

Comment: Im not ruby developer - sorry