# Heroku Rails asset precompile

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, heroku, sass, asset-pipeline

My app worked perfectly locally, but it can't load some `css` file on `Heroku`.

I used `bootstrap gem`, so I change `applocation.css` to `.scss`

Here is **application.scss**

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
@import "clean-blog.min.css";
@import "coda.css.scss";
@import "pagination.css";
@import "posts.scss"
```

Then I run `rake assets:precompile`, and pushed it to `heroku`.

However, it still show request 404 Not Found with  `"clean-blog.min.css"` and `pagination.css`.

Why it would request these two `css` files? Didn't I put them into assest pipeline?

Comment: this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30279590/5531936) for a similar question might help

Comment: It seems not, I delete the `.css`, but when I try to do precompile, it throw more error like `Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after "...orm-group::not(": expected pseudo_expr, was ":first-child)"`. Anyway, I've removed bootstrap file, and changed `application.scss` to `.css` back and fixed this problems.