# sass converting import to import url

Tags: css, sass, gruntjs

New to sass and grunt. All my vendor related css files are in _vendor.scss.

```
@import "public/css/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
```

this converted to 
main.css

```
@import url(public/css/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css);
```

i want it to be

```
@import "public/css/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
```

instead of url how to do it .
cause next i want to use cssjoin to concatinate all import css into one file and cssmin using grunt.

folder structure

```
public ---> scss --->vendor-> _vendor.scss
public ---> css ---> bower_components --> ......
public ----> css ---> main.css
```

grunt tasks

```
    sass: {
        dist: {
            files: {
                'public/css/main.css': 'public/scss/main.scss'
            }
        }
    },

    autoprefixer: {
        dist: {
            options: {
                map: true
            },
            files: {
                'public/css/main.css': 'public/css/main.css'
            }
        }
    },

    watch: {
        css: {
            files: '**/*.scss',
            tasks: ['sass', 'autoprefixer']
        }
    },
```

Comment: You'll have to possibly show us more code and your file structure. It seems like it's not finding the css file at that address so it's assuming it's a URL.

Comment: Can you show us what your grunt task looks like?

Comment: @DominicAquilina  added code n folder structure.

Comment: @KodieGrantham added code n folder structure.

Comment: Yeah, your relative paths seem to be wrong. To get to the bower_components folder from your _vendor.scss file, you would need to '../' your way up a few levels.

Comment: @ppajer tried adding ../ way up but got same result.

Comment: Ooh it's because of the file extensions I think. I'll write it up in a bit

Answer (score 2):

That's because [apparently SASS treats CSS imports differently from SCSS imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7111610/import-regular-css-file-in-scss-file/). If you `@import 'some/file.css'`, it will be compiled to `@import url(some/file.css)` because SASS wants to keep your original CSS import intact (while ironically altering it in a standard manner).

However, if you change the extension your CSS files to `.scss` and import them as such in your main file, the SASS compiler will do its thing and include their contents in place of the original import rule. It simply works because regular CSS syntax is also valid SCSS syntax, and it tricks the compiler into treating your import rule as an SCSS import.

Also, there seems to be no reasonably easy way to alter this behavior and apparently it's not going to change any time soon [based on this ticket open since 2012 that's slowly filling up with workarounds for this exact problem](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/556).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, this solved my error that had me banging my head for hours. I've been trying to give SASS a try after becoming familiar with LESS, but I guess I'll just stick with LESS.