# How can I import external CSS files into my Ember app?

Tags: css, ember.js, sass, font-awesome, google-font-api

I am trying to import Font Awesome and Google Fonts into my Ember app but they aren't working. None of the styles are being applied.

I am using `ember-cli-sass`. Am I *not* able to import a stylesheet from a CDN? Does it not compile `.css` files? I tried looking for a `.scss` file for Font Awesome on a CDN but I couldn't find any, and I don't think Google offers `.scss` files at all.

**app.js**

```
import 'fonts.scss'
```

**fonts.scss**

```
@import '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css';
@import '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,700,800,300';
```

When I add `<i class="fa fa-user"></i>` to my template, none of the Font Awesome styles are applied. Why aren't the stylesheets being imported?

Comment: If you are downloading them via cdn, then you can link your css in the index.html file itself below the app's css link. The better way is to have the dependency in your local vendor folder and referring them in ember-cli-build file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Import regular CSS file in SCSS file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7111610/import-regular-css-file-in-scss-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two main ways to do this. If you don't mind fetching it from the internet, you can add them as links in your `<head>` tag in `index.html`.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,700,800,300" rel="stylesheet">
```

Or you can download the files and include them in your scss build. This gives you more freedom to customize them. You might want to do this to minimize the number of API calls your app requires in order to load, as you've heard that will make your app load faster. But consider that if the fonts you are loading are popular (and these two are) then your user may already have them cached, making them blazingly fast.

---

If you want to download the files into your build here is what you do. Keep in mind that CSS is valid SCSS, so if you can get a CSS file you can always just rename it .scss and include it in your build. But you can't import a file from the internet in your scss. Your scss gets parsed and compiled into CSS before your app even gets served. The files need to be available from your project folders.

## Font Awesome

For FontAwesome 4.7 you can get the sass files and include it in your project pretty easily. Go to http://fontawesome.io/ , click the "Download" button, download the files. You need two folders, the "scss" folder and the "fonts" folder. Add those two folders to your project. Open the `scss/_variables.scss` file and change the `@fa-font-path` to be the path to the font directory. Include the font-awesome.scss file in your scss. You can also find the instructions at http://fontawesome.io/get-started/

[image]

If you want to start to get fancy you can then edit the files to only include the icons you want. There are several ways to do this, but I won't get into that here. It's licensed under the [MIT license](https://opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.html), so you should be able to do this legally.

## Google Fonts

Open a browser and paste http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,700,800,300 into the url. You will actually get the css file. Copy and paste into a .scss file and include it in your build. With Google Fonts each font has its own license. Open Sans is covered by the [Apache 2.0 license](http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0), so you can do this.

Answer (score 0):

There is [no support in SASS for importing a CSS file](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/193)

If you are using Ember, the best way would be to either download the CSS into the [vendors folder](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.13.0/addons-and-dependencies/managing-dependencies/#toc_other-assets) and added to *ember-cli-build.js*.

Alternatively, if you want to use the CDN, you can add the CSS to the index.html in Ember.