# How to import CSS into SCSS file with Jekyll?

Tags: jekyll

This is `style.scss` inside `css` folder, it correctly combines all imports in a single file to `_site/css/style.css` but it doesn't include `normalize.css`

It works only if I change extension to `normalize.scss`

```
---
---

@charset "utf-8";

@import "../../node_modules/normalize.css/normalize.css";
@import "variables";
@import "general";
@import "navigation";
@import "intro";
```

If I skip extension like this than Jekyll doesn't even compile (Error is `Fail to import not found or unreadable`)

```
@import "../../node_modules/normalize.css/normalize";
```

How to import CSS into SCSS file with Jekyll?

Comment: Looks like this is a common problem, see this SO answer for details, be sure to read the comments, they should help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30279590/4276832

Answer (score -1):

You may find your answer in this post: [Import regular CSS file in SCSS file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7111610/import-regular-css-file-in-scss-file)

Source: http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_CHANGELOG.html#CSS__import_Directives

```
CSS @import Directives

Sass is now more intelligent about when to compile @import directives to plain > CSS. Any of the following conditions will cause a literal CSS @import:>

Importing a path with a .css extension (e.g. @import "foo.css").
Importing a path with a media type (e.g. @import "foo" screen;).
Importing an HTTP path (e.g. @import "http://foo.com/style.css").
Importing any URL (e.g. @import url(foo)).
The former two conditions always worked, but the latter two are new.
```