# I can't import css file in my theme.scss from node_modules

Tags: bigcommerce

I have tried css import using @import "../../node_modules/superfish/dist/css/superfish.css"; but I got error

{ [Error: ../../node_modules/superfish/dist/css/superfish.css.scss doesn't exist!]
  formatted: 'Error: ../../node_modules/superfish/dist/css/superfish.css.scss doesn\'t exist!\n        on line 101 of stdin\n>> @import "../../node_modules/superfish/dist/css/superfish.css";\n   --------^\n',
  message: '../../node_modules/superfish/dist/css/superfish.css.scss doesn\'t exist!',
  column: 9,
  line: 101,
  file: 'stdin',
  status: 1 }

Please help me

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7111610/import-regular-css-file-in-scss-file

Answer (score 0):

When you use the @import directive, you can leave off the file extension at the end of the path. Try `@import "../../node_modules/superfish/dist/css/superfish";`

http://sass-lang.com/guide#topic-5

If that doesn't work, you could try uploading the superfish.css file to your assets/scss folder and import it into theme.scss using `@import "superfish";`