# Import Library Stylesheets With Babel-Plugin-React-Css-Modules

Tags: reactjs, webpack, css-modules, babel-plugin-react-css-modules

I am trying to include another library's css for their component in my own application. For reference, I am trying to use this data table library: https://github.com/filipdanic/spicy-datatable.

In the docs, it states `Out of the box, spicy-datatable is bare-bones. Include this CSS starter file in your project to get the look from the demo. Edit it to suit your needs.`

I tried to import the style sheet at the top of the component that I am building like this: `import * as spicy from 'spicy-datatable/src/sample-styles.css';` in my own component file. It was not styled. I tried putting the raw code into my `index.scss` file in my `assets/styles` folder - did not work. I tried putting it in my own styles file `./component.scss` - did not work.

I have them currently set up like:

```
import * as styles from './component.scss';
import * as spicy from 'spicy-datatable/src/sample-styles.css';
```

and am getting an error:

`Module parse failed: Unexpected token (4:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.`

`webpack.config.js`

```
const dirNode = 'node_modules';
const dirApp = path.join(__dirname, 'client');
const dirAssets = path.join(__dirname, 'assets');

/**
 * Webpack Configuration
 */
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    vendor: ['lodash'],
    bundle: path.join(dirApp, 'index')
  },
  resolve: {
    modules: [dirNode, dirApp, dirAssets]
  },
  plugins: [],
  module: {
    rules: [
      // BABEL
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        options: {
          compact: true
        }
      },
      // CSS / SASS
      {
        test: /\.(scss)$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              importLoaders: 1,
              modules: true,
              localIdentName: '[path]___[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
            }
          },
          'sass-loader'
        ]
      },

      // IMAGES
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[path][name].[ext]'
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

`.babelrc`

```
"plugins": [
    [
      "react-css-modules",
      {
        "filetypes": {
          ".scss": {
            "syntax": "postcss-scss"
          }
        },
        "webpackHotModuleReloading": true
      }
    ]
```

I'm not sure if I need to add something to specifically handle `.css` files, this is my first time working with CSS Modules. I thought react-css-modules did that so I'm not quite sure why the CSS file isn't loading correctly.

Edit:

Edited my webpack around to include CSS:

```
  {
        test: /\.(css)$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              modules: true,
              localIdentName: '[path]___[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
            }
          }
        ]
      },
```

Error is gone, but styles still do not appear.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try changing below:

```
import * as spicy from 'spicy-datatable/src/sample-styles.css';
```

to

```
import from 'spicy-datatable/src/sample-styles.css';
```

If you are using CSS-Modules, try below:

```
import spicy from 'spicy-datatable/src/sample-styles.css';
```

and then use the style on JSX element like below:

```
<h1 className={classes.<className in CSS here>}>
```

I setup a codesandbox with the spicy-datatable library and imported the styles and looks like it applied. The styles are in "Hello.css" file and it is imported in "index.js".

https://codesandbox.io/s/4j31xj3689

Answer (score 0):

If library doesn't use css-modules (uses `className` attribute instead of `styleName`) we need to disable modules for imported css, so the class names will remain unchanged. This can be done in 2 ways:

1. Modify your Webpack config

```
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.(css)$/,
            use: [
                'style-loader',
                {
                    loader: 'css-loader',
                    options: {
                        modules: false
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

2. Import library css directly into your scss stylesheet (thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30279590/6268692) pointing out how to perform proper `.css` import). Make sure to exclude `.css` file extension from import line. `:global` directive will prevent css-modules to modify class names for all styles within this directive.

```
:global {
    @import "~library-module-name/.../CssFileWithoutExtension";
}
```