# How to import ngx-datatable css styles, inside angular scss project

Tags: css, angular, sass, ngx-datatable

I have an Angular project with scss styles ext

```
angular.json

"schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
        "styleext": "scss"
    }
},...
```

Then, i have a component that need to use ngx-datatable with themeing, so I import the css files

```
result.component.ts

@Component({
  providers: [HintService],
  selector: 'app-result',
  styleUrls: [
    'result.component.scss',
    '../../../../../node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-datatable/release/index.css',
    '../../../../../node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-datatable/release/themes/material.css',
    '../../../../../node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-datatable/release/themes/bootstrap.css',
    '../../../../../node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-datatable/release/assets/icons.css'
  ],
  templateUrl: 'result.component.html'
})
```

With this code, I dont get the theme working. And I dont get any error of something. I try this then, after reading a similar question [Import regular CSS files in SCSS file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7111610/import-regular-css-file-in-scss-file)

result.component.scss

```
@import "../../../_custom.scss";
@import "~node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-datatable/release/index";
@import "~node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-datatable/release/themes/material";
@import "~node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-datatable/release/themes/bootstrap";
@import "~node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-datatable/release/assets/icons";
```

But in this case, the paths to the fonts inside ngx-datatables css, get messy

```
ERROR in ./src/app/menu/transaction/result/result.component.scss
(Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) CssSyntaxError: C:\TeamProjects\Web\Dev\Portal\node_modules\@swimlane\ngx-datatable\release\assets\icons.css:9:4: Can't resolve 'fonts/data-table.svg' in 'C:\Projects\Web\Dev\Portal\src\app\menu\transaction\result'
```

(the fonts of course are in place, and I don´t have touched the css files of ngx)

Im out of ideas.... can someone point me the right direction?

PD:Sorry my english

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In angular.json, we have styles property which will allow to load third party css files.

```
"styles": [
     "node_modules/angular-calendar/dist/css/angular-calendar.css"
],
```

Comment: I get the project working with this! And the css are working fine, just a question, if I put the reference in the angular.json, its going to get those css globally, is there no other way that respect the styles isolation in the component that needs the style?

Comment: These styles will be attached in the Head Tag of your index.html at run time which will make sure all other components can use it. As far as i know, we can apply View Encapsulation only to the component SASS files.