# CSS files in sass folder - laravel

Tags: css, laravel, sass

I was learning about Laravel Mix that allows us to compile Javascript and CSS files in our project. As I see, in resources/js folder, we can put all the javascript files that should be compiled and in resources/sass folder - all the css files. Using webpacker.mix.js, we import everything in app.js and app.scss but what I want to know is the following: Since, sass files are compiled into CSS, is it possible to import CSS files (and not SASS files) in app.scss? For example, to have this in app.scss:

```
@import ('css/style.css')
```

and not

```
@import ('css/style.scss')
```

?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Import regular CSS file in SCSS file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7111610/import-regular-css-file-in-scss-file)

Comment: Yes, this also answered my question, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Import](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/@import) is not a `sass`, but a plain `css` rule. You can use it to import normal css files, yes.

Comment: Thank you! and also, if I have @import ('css') (css is a folder in resources where there are all my css files), will this be right syntax? Because, when importing _variables.scss file, it starts with underscore. (Actually, I don't know that this underscore does)

Comment: I don't think you can import directories with one statement, but you need to import each file. The underscore in scss or sass indicates that it is not a standalone file, but a file that is going to be imported elsewhere. It helps others to understand your score, and also SASS won't compile files beginning with a `_`. See https://kolosek.com/sass-import/ for details

Comment: @code_locked the underscore tells the compiler that the file is an "include".