# Which tool use to merge CSS and SCSS code

Tags: css, sass, less

Since my code is difficult to read I want to merge some long regular css statements like this:

```
.aui #content .columns-1-2-equal .row-fluid #column-3 header {
 prop1 ...prop2 prop3
}
```

with a current scss document.
So assuming i have a piece of CSS which looks like the previous statement and I have a scss file containing this for example:

```
.aui #content {
  prop4
  .columns-1-2-equal {
    prop5
    .row-fluid {

     #column-3 {
       .header {

        }
      }
  }
```

I want as a result

```
.aui #content {
  prop4
  .columns-1-2-equal {
    prop5
    .row-fluid {

     #column-3 {
       .header {
            // MERGED CODE
            prop1 ...prop2 prop3
        }
      }
  }
```

Is there an automatic way to do it without having to search for the equivalent element in the SCSS tree and copy paste all the properties?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Any changes you make in your SCSS file would be automatically mapped and updated in your generated CSS file.

Comment: Because my code is difficult to read. I want to merge regular css with current scss.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Import regular CSS file in SCSS file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7111610/import-regular-css-file-in-scss-file)

Comment: I don't need to import css. I need to merge existing pure CSS in a SCSS. So 2 pieces of code should become 1 with the brackets and the correct syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you have two files:

**OLD.scss**

```
div {
  width: 300px;
}
```

and

**NEW.scss**

```
@import "OLD.scss";
div {
  color: red;
}
```

First you should run `sass NEW.scss COMBINED.css` it will output:

**COMBINED.css**

```
div {
  width: 300px;
}

div {
  color: red;
}
```

Then `sass-convert COMBINED.css COMBINED.sass` and you will get:

**COMBINED.sass**

```
div {
  width: 300px;
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: Were you able to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

You don't really have to because it will be compiled automatically. But, I get that it can be difficult to read the code in this very long format. I tested this tool and its basic function. Hope this helps for you.

https://www.css2scss.com/

Comment: It even added color variables which I thought was pretty neat.

Comment: Edited my question