# Is there a way to includes, require or routes in SASS/SCSS

Tags: sass, gulp-sass, node-sass, scss-mixins

In PHP, you can use includes or require, and in Laravel, you can create routes. I was wondering if you can do something similar in SASS or SCSS. Or maybe there are Gulp dependencies that will allow PHP includes?

Comment: Could you post a code sample that's equivalent to what you are trying to do? You mentioned you can do this in php, so it could be helpful to show everyone what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: In php i can do  <?php include 'footer.php';?>, I'm wondering is something like that can be done in sass or scss.  I don't want to go to every sass/scss page to changed the footer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Import regular CSS file in SCSS file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7111610/import-regular-css-file-in-scss-file)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it exists. This is called [the `@Import` rule](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/import).