# Scss file not imported properly in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, appfog

My assets are loading correctly in development. However, when I go to push live (on AppFog), I get the following error: "File to import not found or unreadable: bourbon."

This errors is found in the "_bourbon_neat.scss" file, located in my /app/assets/helpers directory. The specific line throwing the error is

```
@import "bourbon";
```

The "bourbon" file isn't actually in the directory structure, but is included in the 'bourbon' gem.

I tried pushing with and without precompiled assets, neither of which seemed to work. I also had a similar problem in another application, using the 'zurb-foundation' library instead. I did manage to get the application running by just pushing continually, but I have no idea why it worked in those instances.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like the bourbon gem is missing or it hasn't added its load paths.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the Bourbon gem in the production environment?

If so, some additional options to try might be:

- Bourbon's documentation indicates you should being importing `bourbon/bourbon` rather than just the parent directory.
- Try defining the path directly to the Bourbon gem for Sass.  Checkout this [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6555799/3100769) that shows how to add to the path variable that Sass cycles through when importing.  Note the "I" flag and the value being passed in.