# Importing Sass through npm

Tags: node.js, sass, npm, node-modules

Currently in our Sass files we have something like the following:

```
@import "../../node_modules/some-module/sass/app";
```

This is bad, because we're not actually sure of the path: it could be `../node_modules`, it could be `../../../../../node_modules`, because of how npm installs stuff.

Is there a way in Sass that we can search up until we find node_modules? Or even a proper way of including Sass through npm?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SASS: Import a file from a different directory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6502313/sass-import-a-file-from-a-different-directory)

Comment: @cimmanon: What? No, that's a completely different question…

Answer (score 79, accepted):

If you are looking for a handy answer in 2017 and are using Webpack, this was the easiest I found.

Suppose your module path is like:

```
node_modules/some-module/sass/app
```

Then in your main scss file you can use:

```
@import "~some-module/sass/app";
```

Tilde operator shall resolve any import as a module.

Comment: simplest of all :)

Comment: It seems to me this only works automatically if you're using Webpack.

Comment: @CTarczon this should be mentioned in the answer, many people, myself included, do not use Webpack to compile their Sass.

Comment: I find myself here a year later, now using Webpack...but why does this solution work?

Comment: FYI - if you're using Parcel bundler instead of webpack, you can omit the tilde ("~").

Comment: Thanks, great, Now please who knows how to import SASS from another domain.
Just the way you have
---> `@import "~some-module/sass/app";`
---> `@import "?http://some-site.com/sass/app";`

Answer (score 18):

As Oncle Tom mentioned, the [new version of Sass has this new `importer` option](https://github.com/sass/node-sass#importer--v200---experimental), where every "import" you do on your Sass file will go first through this method. That means that you can then modify the actual url of this method.

I've used `require.resolve` to locate the actual module entry file.
Have a look at my gulp task and see if it helps you:

```js
'use strict';

var path       = require('path'),
    gulp       = require('gulp'),
    sass       = require('gulp-sass');

var aliases = {};

/**
 * Will look for .scss|sass files inside the node_modules folder
 */
function npmModule(url, file, done) {
  // check if the path was already found and cached
  if(aliases[url]) {
    return done({ file:aliases[url] });
  }

  // look for modules installed through npm
  try {
    var newPath = path.relative('./css', require.resolve(url));
    aliases[url] = newPath; // cache this request
    return done({ file:newPath });
  } catch(e) {
    // if your module could not be found, just return the original url
    aliases[url] = url;
    return done({ file:url });
  }
}

gulp.task("style", function() {
  return gulp.src('./css/app.scss')
    .pipe(sass({ importer:npmModule }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'));
});
```

Now let's say you installed `inuit-normalize` using node. You can simply "require" it on your Sass file:

```css
@import "inuit-normalize";
```

I hope that helps you and others. Because adding relative paths is always a pain in the ass :)

Comment: That's awesome! What file name inside `node_modules/inuit-normalize` would `@import "inuit-normalize"` load?

Comment: "relative paths is always a pain in the sass" FTFY :)

Answer (score 18):

You can add another [includePaths](https://github.com/sass/node-sass#includepaths) to your render options.

**Plain example**

Snippet based on example from Oncle Tom.

```js
var options = {
  file: './sample.scss',
  includePaths: [
    path.join(__dirname, 'bower_components'), // bower
    path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules') // npm
  ]
};

sass.render(options, function(err, result){
  console.log(result.css.toString());
});
```

That should do. You can include the files from package using `@import "my-cool-package/super-grid`

**Webpack and scss-loader example**

```js
{
  test: /\.scss$/, 
  loader: 'style!css!autoprefixer?browsers=last 2 version!sass?outputStyle=expanded&sourceMap=true&sourceMapContents=true&includePaths[]=./node_modules' 
},
```

Notice the last argument, includePaths has to be array. Keep in mind to use [right format](https://github.com/webpack/loader-utils#parsequery)

Comment: This worked for me. Here are more examples of how to specify sass-loader options: https://github.com/jtangelder/sass-loader#sass-options

Answer (score 8):

You can use a Sass `importer` function to do so. Cf. https://github.com/sass/node-sass#importer--v200.

The following example illustrates node-sass@3.0.0 with node@0.12.2:

Install the bower dependency:

```
$ bower install sass-mq
$ npm install sass/node-sass#3.0.0-pre
```

The Sass file:

```
@import 'sass-mq/mq';

body {
  @include mq($from: mobile) {
    color: red;
  }
  @include mq($until: tablet) {
    color: blue;
  }
}
```

The node renderer file:

```
'use strict';

var sass = require('node-sass');
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');

var options = {
  file: './sample.scss',
  importer: function bowerModule(url, file, done){
    var bowerComponent = url.split(path.sep)[0];

    if (bowerComponent !== url) {
      fs.access(path.join(__dirname, 'bower_components', bowerComponent), fs.R_OK, function(err){
        if (err) {
          return done({ file: url });
        }

        var newUrl = path.join(__dirname, 'bower_components', url);

        done({ file: newUrl });
      })
    }
    else {
      done({ file: url });
    }
  }
};

sass.render(options, function(err, result){
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return;
  }

  console.log(result.css.toString());
});
```

This one is simple and not recursive. The `require.resolve` function could help to deal with the tree – or wait until npm@3.0.0 to benefit from the flat dependency tree.

Comment: Awesome, I didn't know about custom importer functions in node-sass. Thanks!

Comment: the includepaths should be used for this

Answer (score 5):

I made the [**sass-npm**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass-npm) module specifically for this.

```
npm install sass-npm
```

In your SASS:

```
// Since node_modules/npm-module-name/style.scss exists, this will be imported.
@import "npm-module-name";

// Since just-a-sass-file isn't an installed npm module, it will be imported as a regular SCSS file.
@import "just-a-sass-file";
```

I normally use gulp-sass (which has the same 'importer' option as regular SASS)

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass'),
    sassNpm = require('sass-npm')();
```

Then, in your `.pipe(sass())`, add the importer as an option:

```
.pipe(sass({
    paths: ['public/scss'],
    importer: sassNpm.importer,
}))
```

Comment: Please fill in the repository field in your package.json!

Comment: Seems pretty similar to the one I wrote, except mine gets the path from the package.json instead of attempting to require styles.scss: https://gist.github.com/callumacrae/09de2b8294339d6a6785

You've written "sass-npm-import" in your docs but it's actually called "sass-npm", by the way.

Comment: @callumacrae repository field added, and README updated, cheers! If you want to add getting sass from `package.json` as a PR go for it!

Comment: None of the systems above describe how to declare what the "main" css file of a package is.

How does (i.e. `sass-npm`) infer this?

Comment: @freepender see the README.

Answer (score 5):

For `dart-sass` and commandline user at 2022, just use the `--load-path` option:

```sh
$ npx sass --load-path=node_modules
```

**Important:** the whole node_modules folder contains so much, just set it launch extremely slow in watch mode. Your should only set your package paths, eg:

```sh
$npx sass -w --load-path=node_modules/foo --load-path=node_modules/bar/scss
```

Answer (score 0):

From offical docuumentation of Sass, adding `~` to imports should do the job.

However, for some reason it did'nt work for me, and sass compiler still complains that the module cannot be found.

Hence, I tried another method which worked for me without any issues. Here's the solution:

- If you are compiling sass files directly from CLI try this:

```
sass src/main.scss dist/main.css --load-path=node_modules
```

- If you are using npm and/or webpack for compiling sass files, add something like this to the `scripts` of `package.json`:

```
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "build": "sass src/main.scss dist/main.css --load-path=node_modules",
    ...
  }
```

Then Run:

```
npm run build
```

- Finally, import your modules like this:

```
@import "some-module/sass/app";
```

To wrap it up, adding `--load-path=node_modules` flag solved the issue permanently. For more information you can check:

```
sass --help
```