# Importing SASS from another npm package

Tags: sass, npm, node-modules

I would like to get little guidance through my next actions. In our company, we are starting to work on a new admin panel. I came with an idea to modularize it to little, more manageable pieces with npm.

First and the most important module, we are working on is *Media Browser*. It's written in React and Sass. It is dependent on another module for now called *framework*, which is kind of foundation for our administration panel. It is also based on Sass and contains all important mixins and variables.

Now, to the question: How can I import mixins and variables to *Media Browser* package? Relative paths differ. Example:

Directory structure when developing Media Browser:

```
node_modules
    framework
        vars.scss
styles.scss
package.json
```

Directory structure when using Media Browser in admin panel:

```
node_modules
    framework
        vars.scss
    media-browser
        styles.scss
package.json
```

Relative paths to *vars.scss* are different.

I am new to npm, so my approach may not be right. I have tried bower too, but I think that with npm@3's flat dependancy tree it is the same.

I have found similar question here:
[Importing Sass through npm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28283652/importing-sass-through-npm), but I would rather avoid some workarounds. IMHO, this should be doable in more elegant way now in npm@3.

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

If you want to import a css file from your node_modules folder use `~`.

Install module: `npm install normalize.css --save`

And then import it in app.scss: `@import '~normalize.css';`

Be sure the entry point of the npm module is correct. You could also do something like `@import '~normalize.css/path/to/build.css';`

Comment: This works for `webpack`. For `node-sass` you have to define your own `--importer` function, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52776781/1534459