# resolving Sass @import from NPM module without Webpack

Tags: npm, sass

Is there a way to do this? I hate the gigantic paths `../../node_modules/etc`

My build tool is NPM scripts and my module bundler is Rollup, if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

For node-sass you can use the option `--importer my-import-script.js`. I personally wanted to use the webpack syntax `~module-name/style.sass` so I defined the importer as:

```
# my-importer-script.js
'use strict';

module.exports = function (url, prev, done) {
  if (url.substring(0, 1) === '~') {
    return { file: __dirname + '/node_modules/' + url.substring(1) };
  } else {
    return null;
  }
};
```