# Importing a SASS file from outside of a rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sass, compass-sass

I'm trying to @import an external SASS file to my rails app with no luck.

The folder structure is as follows

```
- /
  - External_dir
    - sass
      - main.sass <-- file I need

  - Rails_App
    - app
      - assets
        - stylesheets
          - app.sass <-- file where it should be imported
```

I've tried using relative paths (../../../../External_dir/sass/main), absolute paths (/External_dir/sass/main) and symlinks but nothing is working. Does anyone have any ideas? I can't continue without these other styles and I don't want to have to copy them over. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6502313/sass-import-a-file-from-a-different-directory

Comment: the question is similar but the answers aren't working for some reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [cimmanon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1652962/cimmanon) said in the comments this is a duplicate of [SASS: Import a file from a different directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6502313/sass-import-a-file-from-a-different-directory)

The issue had to do with the @imports in the external SASS files using relative paths that the current directory wasn't able to access. By updating the @imports to paths accessible from the current working directory, the SASS was able to import correctly.