# Looking for the SASS Configuration file, MAC

Tags: configuration, sass, installation

Does anyone know where the sass configuration file is located on a mac and for that matter where sass is installed?

I did a "sudo gem install sass" as it stated in the Sass documentation but I don't know where it put the files. I think its tied to ruby somehow?

Comment: Sass doesn't *have* a configuration file.  Why does it matter where Sass is installed?

Comment: Because Zurb Motion-ui documentation says "To import the Sass files into a project, add the load path [modules_folder]/motion-ui/src to your Sass configuration, then @import the library:"

Comment: The Zurb documentation apparently assumes you know what you're doing, and what you need to do greatly depends on your build process.  For vanilla Sass, what you're looking for is this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6502313/sass-import-a-file-from-a-different-directory.  Any "configuration" could possibly exist would be a product of something external to Sass (eg. Compass, Glup, Bower, etc.)

Comment: Thanks for the replies and the problem is I don't know what I am doing. I just wanted to get Sass and Motion-ui working, didn't know it would be so complicated!