# Sass-rails issue importing css

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, sass-rails

I am trying to install a new gem (https://github.com/froala/wysiwyg-rails), it has css dependencies that I'm trying to call using sass-rails but I only see my @import instruction in the rendered css.

The installation worked fine, since I did bundle install, and I can load the js. The css files are in the right folder in my ruby, but I do not succeed in having the css imported.

I am using this line of code to get the css:

```
@import 'wysiwyg-rails/froala_editor.min.css';
```

Is there anything else I have to do with sass-rails to be able to access the files with an import.

Comment: check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6502313/sass-import-a-file-from-a-different-directory

Comment: I've read the thread, I do not see what to do out of it though. Shall I update my subdirectory to add the new gem assets folder. If so how can I do so and how can I check the subdirectories already accessible ?

Comment: Having the same problem, except my file looks like this `@import 'froala_editor.min;`

Comment: How did you install froala?

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, but I ended up using the bower installation and I could access my css files.