# How to import the file that suffix is ‘.scss’ into a sub component of Vue project?

Tags: css, vue.js, sass

This project is coded with Vue.

I want to import a sass file to a sub component.
But the browser reported an error 'File to import not found or unreadable: ../assets/scss/global_css.scss'

I have tried to import 'global_css.scss' into the parent component and delete 'scoped' from < style >.
This approach can be effective！
But I`m afraid this will affect CSS styles among components.I hope to find a better solution.

I have tried to import 'global_css.scss' into < script > of the sub component.(That sounds unreliable, and so does the fact.)

This is the code used to import the 'global_css.scss'.

```
<style scoped lang="scss">
  @import "../../assets/scss/global_css";
</style>
```

(PS.My experience is still shallow. If I have any fault, please forgive me.)

---

This problem has been solved with Uiosun`s help.
He suggested modifying the code in the configuration file.
The code as follows:

```
return {
    css: generateLoaders(),
    postcss: generateLoaders(),
    less: generateLoaders('less'),
    sass: generateLoaders('sass', { indentedSyntax: true }),
    scss: generateLoaders('sass',{data:'@import "../assets/scss/global_css";'}), //Delete the code after the comma
    stylus: generateLoaders('stylus'),
    styl: generateLoaders('stylus'),
  }
```

Corrected code：

```
return {
    css: generateLoaders(),
    postcss: generateLoaders(),
    less: generateLoaders('less'),
    sass: generateLoaders('sass', { indentedSyntax: true }),
    scss: generateLoaders('sass'),
    stylus: generateLoaders('stylus'),
    styl: generateLoaders('stylus'),
  }
```

Success！

Comment: You are forgiven and deeply loved ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can i know file structure of your project?

1. check your loader is right work;
2. may be you can try "relative path" of the sub component file.

eg. `@import "../../assets/scss/global_css";`

Comment: Oh,sorry!The'.. /'was missing when I wrote the question.

Answer (score 0):

If your file structure like this

```
assets
   scss
     global_css.scss 
components
   sub_components
     s_c.vue
```

You should write
`@import "../../assets/scss/global_css"` in `s_c.vue` to import `global_css.scss`.

More information see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6502313/when-using-sass-how-can-i-import-a-file-from-a-different-directory).

Comment: Oh,sorry!The'.. /'was missing when I wrote the question.Thank you for your correction！